# xcolor and everycr-Problem

Tags: tables, color, tex-core, colortbl

I'm trying to insert some `\noalign`-code in every row of a tabular by using `colortbl` and `\everycr` or `\CT@everycr`. In most cases it works fine, but not if there is a `\rowcolors`-command (from `xcolor`) after my command: `\rowcolors` uses this code:

```
\CT@everycr{\@rowc@lors\the\everycr}
```

This doesn't expand `\the\everycr` and so whatever I put in `\everycr` is always ignored. Is this a bug or did I overlook something?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\test{\noalign{\hrule height 0.1cm width 5cm}}
\rowcolors{0}{green}{blue}
%Works after/without \rowcolors:
\CT@everycr\expandafter{\expandafter\test\the\CT@everycr}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
foo & foo\\    foo & foo\\    \multicolumn{2}{l}{blub}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip


%this fails:
\everycr\expandafter{\expandafter\test\the\everycr}
\rowcolors{0}{red}{green}
%\CT@everycr{\@rowc@lors\the\everycr}%inserted by @rowcolors

%it would work if \rowc@lors would use this:
%\CT@everycr\expandafter{\expandafter\@rowc@lors\the\everycr}%
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
foo & foo\\    foo & foo\\    \multicolumn{2}{l}{blub}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It needs to be unexpanded so that things that are added later to `\everycr` get used, otherwise it would only use things that were in `\everycr` at the time of the definition. I'll need to look later to see what's going wrong here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The problem seems to be that tabular is emptying `\everycr` at the start. If I put `\global\everycr{\test}` at the start of the first row at least some of my lines reappears.

Comment: yes latex kernel (and array package) use `\ialign` to initialise tabular. Which means I suppose that formally LaTeX doesn't support use of \everycr :-) However it also means that the code in colortbl (and then xcolor) that carefully re-inserts \the\everycr isn't doing anything useful. Hmmmm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes that sums it up ;-). Btw: It wouldn't work either \rowcolors would use `\CT@everycr\expandafter{\the\CT@everycr\@rowc@lors}` instead (to reuse at least `\CT@everycr`): The content inserted by `colortbl` disturbs the alternating colors. I will have to find some other way to prevent `rowcolors` to kill my code.

Comment: I ran out of time yesterday, hope to look at this later (but first I need to make `bm` work with `unicode-math` :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on David's comments, here's a hack for being able to use `\everycr` in `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,etoolbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{etabular}[1]
 {\patchcmd{\ialign}{\everycr{}}{}{}{}%
  \everycr{#1}%
  \tabular}
 {\endtabular}

\newcommand\test{\noalign{\hrule height 0.1cm width 5cm}}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{0}{green}{blue}
\begin{etabular}{\test}[t]{ll}
foo & foo\\
foo & foo\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{blub}
\end{etabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wouldn't patch globally `\ialign`; however this would make all nested tabulars the same `\everycr`. Use `\begin{etabular}{}[pos]{columns}` for nested tabulars inside an `etabular`.

For `longtable` you can use a very similar patch:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{elongtable}[1]
 {\patchcmd{\LT@array}{\everycr{}}{}{}{}%
  \everycr{#1}%
  \longtable}
 {\endlongtable}
\makeatother
```

since `\LT@array` is responsible of saying `\everycr{}`.

Comment: This doesn't work if I replace `\tabular` by `longtable` but I don't have currently the time to find out why. (The actual problem which led to the question was that I wanted to reset the rowcolors in a longtable at the start of a new page).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\LT@array` says `\everycr{}`. The patch is just the same.

Comment: Yes the patch works - and shows that longtable doesn't handle the `\noalign` as expected: The line are before the first row. Tabulars are complicated beasts ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There is a rule before the table (and it's not too much of a surprise), but also an additional one a the end, which has possibly to do with what `longtable` has to do at breaks.